Uniform convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$
Consider
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
It is pretty clear that it converges pointwise to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ and it's also not hard to see that it converges uniformly on all bounded intervals. However, does it converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?
This is particularly interesting because I am pretty sure that because of the uniform convergence on bounded intervals, we have that its limit is continuous (and by an analogous argument for the derivatives) and differentiable everywhere.

The series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
converges uniformly on all bounded intervals,
but it doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$:
please note that
$$\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\sin\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\sin\frac{n}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{n+n}}\sin\frac{n}{n+n}\\
\geq\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\sin\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\sin\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{n+n}}\sin\frac12\to\infty.$$
PS: Cauchy umiform convergence test: $\sum f_n(x)$ convergents uniformly on $D$ if and only if,
for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that when $n>N$, we have
$$|f_{n+1}(x)+\cdots+f_{n+p}(x)|<\epsilon,\quad \forall x\in D,\forall p\in\mathbb N^+.$$

Nice! Minor detail: Seems like copy+paste betrayed you by a factor of $\sqrt{n+1}/\sqrt{n+n}$ in the last term of the sums.

Thanks@
M A Pelto

Thank you @Riemann for your nice solution. I appreciate your insight!

Too long for a comment.
We know that
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\,dn=2 \sqrt{n} \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-2 \sqrt{2 \pi x} \, C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 x}{\pi  n} }\right)$$
$$\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\,dn=2 \sqrt{2 \pi x} \, C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }} \right)-2 \sin (x)$$ where appear the Fresnel cosine integral (I assumed $x>0$).
This function looks to be a nice "envelope" of the summation. Asymptotically, it is almost $\sqrt{2 \pi x}$.

Sorry @claude, I don't exactly follow how this demonstrates the result. Is it some sort of comparison argument? If you are willing to elaborate, I would appreciate that.

@nashpilled. It was just a comment because the continuous case looks interesting to me. No more. Cheers :-)
